# Google Tag Manager Tracking for sorting

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to add some tracking parameter in google tag manager for sorting function based on price. I wanted to know what could potentially be event action, category and label?

Comment: Have you read the docs? if not, have a look at [this page](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en). I hope it helps!

Comment: You could also use a custom dimension.